# Dual boot machine, not obvious how the boot sequence finds GRUB or how to remove it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, grub

I have a dual booting system (Windows and Ubuntu) where I am trying to remove Ubuntu and its partitions.

The internal drive (laptop) is divided as follows:

- 350MB System Reserved (mounted as P:)
- 150GB Windows 10 (C:)
- 32GB  Linux Swap
- 150GB Linux OS (Mounted in ext2fsd as G:)
- 600GB Shared NTFS partition (I:)

The system reserved partition has a `/boot` directory with no mention of Ubuntu.

The windows partition has a `/boot` folder, also with no mention of Ubuntu

The Linux OS partition has a `/boot` folder with
a `grub` subfolder and `grub.cfg`. The GRUB config file appears to reference linux and Windows, but it is not clear if it is current.

Does this suggest the boot information on the Windows 10 drive is not complete/not bootable, if it has been skipped by the BIOS/UEFI?

The Windows 10 Partition was not marked as Active, however marking it Active has made no difference to the boot process (it still goes to grub).

How is the boot partition being evaluated and how can I eliminate grub?

Comment: Was this originally a UEFI or BIOS install?

Comment: UEFI settings > Boot should be enough to boot Windows directly, as always with UEFI mode. Then you can remove the Ubuntu only partitions. Removing the boot entry to "Ubuntu" (Grub) is optional, there's absolutely NO difference with or without it and Windows bootloader manager set as the 1st priority.

Comment: I believe it was a UEFI installation. @ChanganAuto are you expecting that to be in the BIOS? My BIOS can choose between UEFT and local disk, but neither change the behaviour.

Comment: BIOS doesn't exist *de facto* since 2012 in the consumer/prosumer market. So, I'm expecting UEFI ("BIOS") settings, Boot menu to have typical UEFI entries at least for both OSes - "Windows bootloader manager" and "Ubuntu" -. But it can be the case that you installed in Legacy mode (AKA "BIOS mode") in which case you have to boot Windows installation media and repair boot before anything else (this removes Grub and installs Windows (legacy) bootloader instead).

Comment: Aha, 2011 spec HP Elitebook.

Comment: So likely BIOS *in which case you have to boot Windows installation media and repair boot before anything else (this removes Grub and installs Windows (legacy) bootloader instead)*. Then you can go ahead and delete the Ubuntu only partitions.